# Is $\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{A}^{T}$ irreducible?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider irreducible nonnegative matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbf{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$  such that $a_{ij} \in [0,1)$ as element of $\mathbf{A}$ of period $p$. If $\mathbf{A}^{T}$ is transpose of $\mathbf{A}$, then

- Is $\mathbf{A}^{T}$ is irreducible of a period $p$?
- Is $\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{A}^{T}$ is irreducible of a period $p$?

Actually, I want to use Perron–Frobenius theorem to show that the eigenvector of $\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{A}^{T}$ is positive. I don't have any idea how to prove $\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{A}^{T}$ is irreducible of a period $p$.

If the answer is YES, how I can prove it?

If NO, could you give me a counterexample?

Please I need help!

Thank you very much!

Comment: What does “period $p$” mean in this circumstance?

Comment: The period of an irreducible matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is the greatest common divisor (GCD) of the lengths of loops in the directed graph G($\mathbf{A}$
).

Comment: ok. I edited it.

Comment: You definitely show that $A^\top$ is also irreducible of degree $p.$ Since the $a_{ij}\geq 0,$ you can also show that $A+A^\top$ is irreducible. But that matrix can have added loops, so the period possibly drops..

Comment: note that $(A+A^T)$ is symmetric so it necessarily has period $\in\{1,2\}$ .  (You can verify this in terms of reversibility or looking at the spectrum possibilities for the maximum modulus eigenvalue.)  As for irreducibility: write out the definition and common criteria / tests used then try applying them.  Doing this for $A^T$ should be immediate and doing it for $(A+A^T)$ really just comes down to putting in the mechanical effort.